# Emacs noweb font size changes code chunk

Tags: emacs, font-size, ess

I am using Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darvin, NS apple-appkit 1038.36) of 2013-03-13 on bob.porkrind.org.

I try to compile a Latex document using knitr to compile R code and implement it into a Latex document.

Changing the font size with C-x C-+ works fine, however when the cursor comes into a R code chunk, seperated by "<<>> @" the font size automatically "jumps back" to the global font size and stays that way when moving out of the code chunk.

Any ideas how to make to font size stay permanent in and out of code chunks?

Comment: put your cursor on the code, and do M-x describe-face. That will give you the face R code uses and should show you the :height attribute, most likely :height will be set and you'll need to set it to nil using set-face-attribute so that it'll just inherit the height from the default face, there may be multiple faces in the R code that you need to do this for